# bipartite network Degree-preserving randomization with constraints

Tags: python, networkx, bipartite, randomized-algorithm

I am working on a sample data containing several papers, the topics they belong to, and the publication years of those papers, it looks like this:

| paper_id | topic | pub_year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2031361154 | 0 | 1998 |
| 2088633475 | 1 | 1995 |
| 1987003396 | 2 | 1995 |
| 2246118404 | 3 | 1992 |
| 2017547909 | 1 | 1996 |
| 2032449907 | 4 | 1993 |
| 2053684599 | 0 | 1991 |
| 1968369145 | 1 | 1997 |
| 2160198778 | 4 | 1997 |
| 2026639487 | 3 | 1991 |

I am trying to reshuffle the publication years of those papers (keep the number of papers in each topic and published in each year constant) as preparation for a null model.  If without constraints, this can be done simples by `np.random.permutation`. An example table after reshuffling the publication year is like this:

| paper_id | topic | reshuffled_pub_year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2031361154 | 0 | 1998 |
| 2088633475 | 1 | 1997 |
| 1987003396 | 2 | 1995 |
| 2246118404 | 3 | 1992 |
| 2017547909 | 1 | 1996 |
| 2032449907 | 4 | 1993 |
| 2053684599 | 0 | 1991 |
| 1968369145 | 1 | 1997 |
| 2160198778 | 4 | 1995 |
| 2026639487 | 3 | 1991 |

But I want to ensure that the reshuffled years of those papers stay inside the period of the corresponding topics. For example, in the first table, there are papers about topic 1 published only in 1995, 1996, and 1997, so the reshuffled years of all papers about topic 1 stay the period from 1995 to 1997. Similarly, topic 0 in [1991,1998], topic 2 in [1995], topic 3 in [1991,1992] and topic 4 in [1993,1997]. But in the second table, the reshuffled publication year of paper 2246118404 is 1998, as this paper is about topic 3, the year can only be 1991 or 1992. So I need to specify the constraints during the reshuffle.

I have searched web pages and papers about this, I think this question can be modeled as a bipartite network degree-preserving randomization with constraints. The two node types in this bipartite network are topic and pub_year and an example network is given as the following figure:

[example network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KStfp.png)

To reshuffle the links in this bipartite network, I tried `configuration_model` in `networkx` using python. So I can guarantee the degrees of topics and years (But this is not different from `np.random.permutation`?).  But as far as I know, `configuration_model` does not accept any constraint. In this example, tp1 has links to y1 and y2. So, in a desired reshuffled network, tp1 cannot have links to y3 and y4. Similarly, no links between (tp2,y4), (tp3,y1/y3), (tp4,y1/y2).

I would like to know if I am going in the right direction, i.e., modeling this task as a bipartite network reshuffle problem. If so, is there any tool that I can use for this task?

Comment: It's quite unclear what are you trying to do. Can you provide a simple example of data before and after randomization?

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky Thank you for asking. I have edited the question. In the first table, you can see an example of original data. In the second table, it's the data after randomization. The first two columns stay unchanged, only the third column (pub_year) is  reshuffled.

Answer (score 0):

A simple script to do the yaer shuffling:

```
import random

# replace it with your data
papers = [
    {"paper_id": 2031361154, "topic": 0, "year": 1998},
    {"paper_id": 2088633475, "topic": 1, "year": 1995},
    {"paper_id": 1987003396, "topic": 2, "year": 1995},
    {"paper_id": 2246118404, "topic": 3, "year": 1992},
    {"paper_id": 2017547909, "topic": 1, "year": 1996},
    {"paper_id": 2032449907, "topic": 4, "year": 1993},
    {"paper_id": 2053684599, "topic": 0, "year": 1991},
    {"paper_id": 1968369145, "topic": 1, "year": 1997},
    {"paper_id": 2160198778, "topic": 4, "year": 1997},
    {"paper_id": 2026639487, "topic": 3, "year": 1991}
]

topicRanges = {}
for paper in papers:
    topic = paper["topic"]
    if topic in topicRanges:
        topicRanges[topic] = {
            "min": min(paper["year"], topicRanges[topic]["min"]),
            "max": max(paper["year"], topicRanges[topic]["max"])
        }
    else:
        topicRanges[topic] = {"min": paper["year"], "max": paper["year"]}

shuffled = []
for paper in papers:
    topic = paper["topic"]
    topicRange = topicRanges[topic]
    year = random.randint(topicRange["min"], topicRange["max"])
    shuffled.append(
        {"paper_id": paper["paper_id"], "topic": topic, "year": year})

print(shuffled)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also want to keep the number of papers published each year a constant. In my example, there are two papers published in 1991, one in 1992, one in 1993 and etc. But in your method, this is not guaranteed. I guess a possibility is to add a list of candidate years, each time in the iteration `for paper in papers' , we filter the candidate list by the topicRanges and randomly select one. At the end of the loop, we delete the selected year from the list. Do you think this works?

Comment: However, the possibility I mentioned above doesn't make sure we can always find an result as sometimes the candidate list of years can be empty.

Comment: Maybe I miss something but the requirement to keep the number of papers per year contradics the very idea of randomization by year with fixed year range per topic...

Comment: In fact, the two requirements are not completely contradictory. Consider a case where topic 1 is in a year range [1991,2000] and topic 2 in a year range [1995,2003]. Randomization with respect to both the two requirements keeps the papers about topic 1 published from 1991 to 1994 unchanged, papers about topic 2 published from 2001 to 2003 unchanged. And the reshuffle only applies to papers published between 1995 and 2000 (i.e., the intersection of the two year ranges).